# Unable to bypass CORS in my Flask and React app

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am getting CORS error most of the time even if i give access to all origins its giving the same issue

[image: CORS ERROR]

Here is my code in Flask

[image]

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #   app.run(port=5000)
      socketio.run(app, debug=True)
```

your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that you have is that your server is responding with a 403 response instead of a 200 response. Any idea why the server is responding with a 403? Socket.IO does not return 403 responses, so this must be coming from your own application or another extension you are using.

CORS in this case is a secondary problem, because this 403 response that your server returns does not provide CORS headers. But this is not the main problem, you need to fix the 403 issue for things to start working.